# Error while sharing link on Facebook wall using feed dialog (URL Redirection)

Tags: facebook, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

**ANSWER**

You need to set redirect URL in [Facebook Developers: Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).

[image]

---

I am using [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) to share URL in my Windows 8 app, but I am getting below given error. I searched about it & found that I should turn off sandbox mode but then also it's not working. Am I doing anything wrong?

[image]

**Working Using YouTube App ID**

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=87741124305&link=http://www.stackoverflow.com&feature=share&display=popup&name=Stack%20Overflow&picture=http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png&redirect_uri=https://www.youtube.com/facebook_redirect&description=Stack%20Overflow%20is%20a%20question%20and%20answer%20site%20for%20professional%20and%20enthusiast%20programmers.

**Not Working Using My App ID**  [UPDATE : I've removed the app ID]

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=XXXXXXXXXX&link=http://www.stackoverflow.com&feature=share&display=popup&name=Stack%20Overflow&picture=http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png&redirect_uri=https://www.youtube.com/facebook_redirect&description=Stack%20Overflow%20is%20a%20question%20and%20answer%20site%20for%20professional%20and%20enthusiast%20programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redirect_uri` must match your `Site URL` in App setting.

To make it work **for now** change 
`redirect_uri` to `http://www.facebook.com` it's fallback works with all Apps

[So the your new URL is.. Click here :)](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=159248604260839&link=http://www.stackoverflow.com&feature=share&display=popup&name=Stack%20Overflow&picture=http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com&description=Stack%20Overflow%20is%20a%20question%20and%20answer%20site%20for%20professional%20and%20enthusiast%20programmers.&to=100000692924752)

Comment: Thanks :) Where can I set the site URL?

Comment: [Facebook Developers: Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) But Don't set it to `http://www.facebook.com` leave it empty, Because that URL above in My answer was a hint to make sure you are not facing any problems with your app.